# How many sequences can be created in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, sequence

So, how many sequences can be created in PostgreSQL ?

Is there any limit for it ?
Or I can create millions of sequences ?

Comment: Yes, you can create millions of sequences. But it's hard to believe that you really need this. The upper limit is just above 2 billion.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve with that many sequences?

Comment: @FrankHeikens, I need to have payment number sequence which is made in some organization, and it must depend on organization_id. So, in each organization - unique payment number sequence. Organizations will be many, so I need many sequences

Comment: In that case it won't matter if you have one sequence for all organisations, you have a unique number. In both cases you might have a gab between the numbers, that's how a sequence works. See the manual: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-sequence.html

Comment: @FrankHeikens there is should't be a gap. When organization is created, I create  ```organization_123_payment_sequence```, then ```organization_456_payment_sequence```. And when I handle PaymentCreation, I know in which organization that payment has been made. And ```select next_val``` from specific sequence for specific organization.